# Rails 6: how to use <script> tag in html file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello and have a good day!
While building my own Rails app, I encounter this problem. Rails 6 use webpacker by default:

```
<head>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'file_name' %>
</head>
```

which will load the **file_name.js** from **./app/javascript/packs** into the asset pipeline

*But*
, I don't want this.
I want to use the good ol' days html `<script src="/assets/file_name.js"></script>`
In other words, load the file directly into the view in development environment.
The reason for this is that it is **the proven method** of fast and comfortably develop with javascript.
Meanwhile, webpacker will be used in production environment for speed loading and later, scalability.
I can't find any question relating to this problem. Thus, I am here to ask for help.
How can I use `<script>` tag to include js file in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `javascript_include_tag` helper to include a script in your view.

```
javascript_include_tag "my-awesome-js"
# => <script src="/assets/my-awesome-js.debug-1284139606.js"></script>
```

This will load compiled files from the asset pipeline, not from webpack. It's slightly different to the `javascript_pack_tag` helper which you mention, which loads packs from webpack.

You will need to ensure you've added your JS files to your `app/assets/config/manifest.js` file for them to be available for you to load in this way.

Comment: I know how to use Sprocket though, my `./app/assets/config/manifest.js` have this `//= link_directory ../javascripts .js` but again, it is still a generated file, not loading directly like an html would load a javascript file

Comment: It will essentially be loaded directly in development. I don't see why this is a problem.

Comment: Jon, here is an image explain it, Chrome Dev Tools: [link](https://i.postimg.cc/9fPspTJr/Untitled.png) The green tick mean that the file can be edited in Dev Tools, even in the middle of debugging process. And any changes is saved directly into the file

Comment: Thus, it allow run the code and stop at desired line, messing with local variables and logic in the console, adjust the code and keep running to the next line without the need to restart. The new code is run and also saved. It's like ajax for javascript ... developing

Comment: And I have to correct my previous claim, that script tag don't allow this "hot" edit feature. It's still generate a new js file with the same name.

Comment: Jon, I know my way of work sounds absolute blasphemy to you. I understand. It's just that I prefer that of a normal html file loading js file. And I still have no answer for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In a view: `javascript_include_tag "/lib/jslib.js"` (note the `/` in front is necessary)
This loads `my_app/public/lib/jslib.js`

If desired it can then be added to a workspace in devtools in order to allow saving direct edits to the file system.

I use this when I don't want to include a library in a webpack bundle, typically because it powers a rarely used feature and it's not worth adding the weight to the entire app's js bundle when most users will never need it.

Answer (score -2):

Just include the script tag in any view_name.html.erb file. If you are going to use it across the application, put the tag in application.html.erb file in app/view/layouts folder.

Comment: `<script src="javascripts/file_name.js"></script>`
give me this:
`GET http://localhost:3000/javascripts/file_name.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Just put your file file_name.js in /public direction. Then in the layout file, you can use     <script src="../../file_name.js" />

Comment: Only files in the public folder can be directly accessed by linking.

Comment: HOLY SHIT!!! It works. If I put the files in `public` folder I can use it directly with `<script src="file_name.js" />`. which will look for the `./public/file_name.js`

Comment: Don't do this. You wont have unique filename fingerprints, and so people will be at risk of loading a cached copy of your JS files and not getting the most recent version. Use the asset pipeline (or webpack) ... it's what they're designed for!

Comment: @Jon oh, thanks for the friendly reminder. but I intend to use it for **development** environment, which already disable caching and need to load the file directly not the generated file

Comment: Still ... don't do that. Development code becomes production code. Just do it properly. You're not gaining anything by doing it this way. It's not even easier.

Comment: @NeerajShukla hey, I have to correct my previous comment and take back the green tick ): the <script> tag still generate a new js file, not load it like an html would load an js file. It pretty much work like Sprocket's `javascript_include_tag` ):